# Reinstalling Unity Ubuntu 14.04 with crouton causes some programs to not appear after installation

Tags: 14.04, unity, backup, chromebook, crouton

I currently have a crouton ChromeOS/Ubuntu laptop, and this morning I got the "ChromeOS is missing" message which meant I needed to reinstall ChromeOS, and in turn, Ubuntu. I had a recovery flash drive so I was able to get it up and running, and I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 once again and recovered my backup I made from around a month ago.

The problem is, a lot of things that were available from when I installed last time weren't available this time around, like the backup utility (which I've now learned is `deja-dup`), Synaptics, and some others.

In the past 6 months I've had this chromebook I've reinstalled ChromeOS & Ubuntu around 4 or 5 times, the longest stretch of time without reinstalling being these past 4 months; and I've noticed that this has happened many times before. Sometimes when installing these programs don't show up after installing, sometimes they do, sometimes they don't once again. I don't know what's the cause of this, but I figured I'd head here and try to ask about it.

Does anyone know what could be the possible cause of this? Are there maybe some packages that I'm missing? I'm fairly certain I've installed Ubuntu the exact same way I did last time (I used `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t unity,extension` for this reinstall), so I'm not sure what could be going wrong here.

I apologize for the wall of text and if this doesn't fit here, but I'm very confused about the cause and this is the first place I thought of. Sorry if anything here was confusing, I just woke up an hour ago and the first thing I did was deal with this stuff, so I'm trying to get this out as quick as possible. Any help is appreciated and I can provide some more info if needed, thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally, I recommend just leaving Ubuntu installed and installing [Neverware](https://www.neverware.com/#introtext-3) beside it. If you do decide to do this and you have ChromeOS installed right now, leave it installed before you install Ubuntu. There is no way, as far as I know, to make the Neverware bootable without Windows, macOS, or ChromeOS. I had to use my grandmother's Chromebook to make the bootable to try it. Neverware is _just_ like ChromeOS except that there are extra features if you're like a school or something and you need to be able to administer the system, push updates and

Comment: such. The only difference between the free version and ChromeOS is that the free version of Neverware uses Chromium. Other than, AFAIK, everything is exactly the same so you can have, essentially, ChromeOS installed alongside Ubuntu so you don't have to use crouton which doesn't run nearly as well as a full installation.